# Type for recursively remapping keys of "flattened" object into nested one (using template literals)

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I'm attempting to express type to a function that takes an object with keys as dot delimited paths and returns a new object, where all sub-paths are expanded. I can't wrap my head around how would one preserve the original type for a given path while recursively 'de-structuring' them.

```
// Dummy structure
const flattenedObject = {
    'd.a': 1,
    'd.b': true,
};

type FlattenedObject = typeof flattenedObject;

// Expected type (or union of sub-paths: `{ d: { a: number } } | { d: { b: boolean } }`)
interface NestedObject {
    d: {
        a: number;
        b: boolean;
    }
}

// Attempt
type MapNestedKeys<R, N extends keyof R = keyof R, N0 = N> = N0 extends string
  ? N0 extends `${infer K1}.${infer K2}`
    ? { [K in N as `${K1}`]: MapNestedKeys<R, N, K2> }
    : { [K in N as N0]: R[K] }
  : {};

// Gives union, but types for nested keys are now union on all key types
type Test = MapNestedKeys<FlattenedObject>;
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFcFtoT1AZwC4CdIGNmVQUwFAYD2AdiqAGYA2AhssribgCYDyARgFa5agC8oAN75Qo0AHJmAOhriAXKACMAGhFjJU9vNBpIuVQF8A3PnzI4AB1ygAYrXqMWHbrwHmrRCpXsMmbLjzIJvggoACiAB5WWCw6ltYUqETQoOy4VEQA7qAAFESooJAkAJakoJ5IkOwAtBZ0ABaICkKgzAqCoDQKJDBpBQagAwA%20LW0t7ArsRERUuDQkg4MAlPjFJAyoFDQY1gByuChOAbzCYq3tameiXaA90H0mV2ITqdOz849iBvjfIWAAgg5oBZkGZ4qAALI0Cz7Q7MADSuDgiAAPAAlZSgXagXARXzMRCgADWSIqaP4xNJXgxWIADBTdgA%20Bn03H4wkoVBrADmagA-HScXjGATQAADAAkgjWFFwBXhigMUilMrloHhACYDGLLqABR0ANrw0BrLGdQmSwQK7UAXQUUJhBwYCKRqJpu0xmuZ3zO7VARpNC2xNEJu1pdtAaKNNsGanaxlMoQA4sUAG4HQolUiY9iQZBxKyEij5W5O2Ik5GdPC3LKZ0oLMo0KhUSkIdwHMFWUAAFSdFIdsOdiORKLsdF8RxcyEZJiAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach that works a bit better with various depths of the path (e.g. 'd.a.c')

```
type MapNestedKeys<T, P = keyof T> = 
   P extends `${infer K1}.${infer K2}` & keyof T ?
      MapNestedKeys<{[S in K1]: MapNestedKeys<{[S1 in K2]: T[P]}>}>  : 
   P extends string & keyof T ? {[S in P]: T[P]} : {}
```

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova, nice solution. I like how you used `& keyof T` instead of using condition statement

Comment: @captain-yossarian thank you! I find it strange we need to do this check at all, considering that being keyof T is the definition of P

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```js
// Dummy structure
const flattenedObject = {
  'a.b.c.d.e': 1,
  'f.g.h.j.k': true,
};

type FlattenedObject = typeof flattenedObject;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type MakeObj<Prop, Value> =
  Prop extends string ?
  Prop extends `${infer Head}.${infer Tail}` ?
  { [Key in Head]: MakeObj<Tail, Value> }
  : Prop extends string ? { [K in Prop]: Value }
  : never
  : never

type Iterate<Obj> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: MakeObj<Prop, Obj[Prop]>
}>

type Result = Iterate<FlattenedObject>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFcFtoT1AZwC4CdIGNmVQUwFAYD2AdiqAGYA2AhssribgCYDyARgFa5agC8oAN75QoAOQ0AdO0kZJzSbjEAuUAEYANCPEVJAc0kALSZ0kBrFaDSRcWgL4BufPmRwADrlAAxWvUYsObl4BVw8iCkpfBiY2Lh5kJxd3TwA1GiobRAAeABUAPn5QHIBtM1w4cKKAXWdQzwBZGjLArIAFVCI3DVA0jNwCvm12ztBcAA9o5kQkNABLEj1QAH4hjrdRicYp0AADABJBeYpcVFAACVwaZjtJA6OToppZqjsd5e1BUGKAaXLQefOl2YVVUjWaXFyTyo3V6NgKdm0qmG63Gk2mKFQ80WSyEX2%20-xIoGRIJ66RsoARolUTAAbidEaBafSkh5QABJBioOi4LKBAakvrZYSiYrIgmgMoVCKBElg3AtZHdQKitZVPL4OzqlmeABKuEQkCoyEKHJO3KyPjo0QCcSweSAA)

Comment: Thanks! Works with two levels (example in question), but gives union of key types on single level and never on level >= 3.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it. My bad